# Exporting data from Teradata - Append issue

Tags: powerbi, teradata

I'm manually exporting data from teradata into .txt

As this needs to be done daily, I choose to append the new data into the previous file.

The issue here is there's spaces and lines in between the days causing errors when importing files into PBI

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef8UO.png)

Anyone knows how to get rid of these so the data doesn't have any blank rows between the days?

Thanks

Comment: How are you exporting your data?  Why don't you point PowerBI directly against Teradata?

Comment: I'm exporting the data from previous day into a .txt file in to the cloud to avoid having 90 million rows at the end of the year. If I perform a direct query from PBI I will have to query 365 days by 31 Dec 2021

Comment: As @Andrew says: 1) this isn't a question about Teradata or about PowerBI, this is a question about whatever client tool you are using to export / append the data; and 2) storing / appending data on the client side doesn't seem like a good design choice - a summary table or join index on the database side seem like a better way, if in fact processing 90 million rows is an issue. (It may not be.)